# How long do batteries typically last in electronic deadbolts?

Tags: security, locks, doors

I'm considering getting a [Schlage Plymouth Keypad](http://consumer.schlage.com/Products/Pages/ProductDetails.aspx?ModelNumber=FE365%20PLY%20619%20FLA) for our front-door but was curious how long the 9V battery typically lasts. The web site says "3 year battery life" but I'm... skeptical. =)

Has anyone used these types of locks before and if so, do the batteries need to be replaced often?

-M

[image]

Comment: Just a quick follow-up to this post.  We've had this lock for over 2 years now and it's still going strong (with the stock batter). Since the bolt is turned by hand, I think it helps conserve battery life.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've used something similar on my front door for about 4 years now (4xAA instead of a 9V) and it's great not having to carry keys *everywhere*. On average, I change the batteries about **every 12-18 months**. I guess it all depends on how often you use it and how worried you are about getting locked out.  Personally I don't bother testing the batteries because mine beeps angrily when they start to get low.

Answer (score 4):

I used one of these with 4xAA's in an apartment with 6 college students who themselves and friends were coming and doing all day long. It was an older model and lasted about 8 months on average, which seems like pretty good mileage. They are also good about warning you when the batteries are low.

Living without keys was great.